# Calcular uma data a partir de uma data inicial e um prazo

Tags: javascript

Preciso que ao selecionar uma data de início e um período (em meses) o script calcule em meses a data final.

Detalhe: ao clicar fora do campo período já faça todo o cálculo exibindo a data final no campo correspondente.

Não tenho nada pronto ainda devido a minha falta de conhecimento em JavaScript.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gustavo, mesmo você deixando claro sobre seu conhecimento em JS, tire um tempo para conhecer como funciona a comunidade em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talvez tenha ficado um pouco grande o JS, mas já faz bem o que tu pediu.

```js
function calcDate() {
  var dat = document.getElementById("data").value;
  var meses = document.getElementById("meses").value;
  if(dat != "" && meses != "") {
    var sp = dat.split("/");
    dat = new Date(sp[2], sp[1]-1, sp[0]);
    var m = meses%12;
    var y = Math.floor(meses/12);
    var tmp = dat.setMonth(dat.getMonth()+m);
    var tmp = dat.setYear(dat.getFullYear()+y);
    var f = new Date(tmp);
    document.getElementById("final").value = ("0" + f.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (f.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

```html
<input onblur="calcDate()" id="data" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
<input onblur="calcDate()" id="meses" type="number" placeholder="Prazo em meses">
<input id="final" readonly placeholder="Data Final">
```

Comment: notei que esta funcionando, porém a data final não esta sendo gerada certa... por exemplo a data de hoje 08/02/2017 + 12 = 08/02/2018 ou 08/02/2017 + 1 = 08/03/2017

Comment: Fiz alguma alteração verifica se agora ficou ok?!

Comment: agora sim esta ok, MUITO obrigado !!!

Comment: no chrome e no firefox a data final esta saindo assim "aN/aN/NaN", alguma solução?

Comment: Eu estou no chrome e não verifiquei esse erro, imagino que seja culpa do `input="date"` deixa eu dar uma olhada

Comment: @GustavoSamuelMarcolin agora funciona?

Comment: não esta funcionando, esta gerando ainda "aN/aN/NaN" ...estranho

Comment: Faz o seguinte, consegue segurar até de tarde? Eu vou testar em todos os browsers ao meio dia e atualizo pra ti!

Comment: sim, pode ser..